# C++ Communicating with Dll's gone wrong

Tags: c++, string, char, assert

My current project has 2 dll's, one called Engine and another called Graphics. The Engine links to the graphics. And then the main program with links to both, but uses the Engine.

In some functions like this:

```
typedef const char* ce_safechar;
AssimpIntegration::GetData(ce_safechar pFile, ...
```

this error pops up: **_pFirstBlock == pHead**, just after i exited the function.

I have seen many different issues and it all seems to point at strings.

How can I avoid such behavior?

Full Function if needed:

```
FMESH_DATA AssimpIntegration::GetData(ce_safechar pFile, bool convLeftHanded, int maxSM)
{
    // Create an instance of the Importer class
    Assimp::Importer importer;
    // And have it read the given file with some example post processing
    // Usually - if speed is not the most important aspect for you - you'll 
    // probably to request more post processing than we do in this example.

    int cls = 0x0;
    if (convLeftHanded)
        cls = aiProcess_ConvertToLeftHanded;

    const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile( pFile, aiProcess_GenNormals | aiProcess_FindInstances | aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace | cls | aiProcess_Triangulate  );

    // If the import failed, report it
    if (!scene)
    {
        char* error = (char*)importer.GetErrorString();
        CE_ERROR(error, "Assimp Error");
    }

    // Now we can access the file's contents. 
    Group<MESH_STRUCT> Vertices;
    Group<DWORD> indices;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////PROCESS MESH///////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    FMESH_DATA data;

    if (scene->HasAnimations())
    {
        aiAnimation *anim = scene->mAnimations[0];

        FOREACH(anim->mChannels[0]->mNumPositionKeys)
        {
            aiVector3D position = anim->mChannels[0]->mPositionKeys[i].mValue;

            CE_ANIMATIONKEY key;
            key.position = D3DXVECTOR3(position.x, position.y, position.z);

            data.Keys.push_back(key);
        }
    }

    D3DXVECTOR3 norms;
    float tanx, tany, tanz;
    float bitanx, bitany, bitanz;

    FOREACH (scene->mNumMeshes)
    {
        if (i >= maxSM)
            continue;

        aiMesh *mesh = scene->mMeshes[i];
        Vertices.group.clear();
        indices.group.clear(); //dafuck?

        if (mesh->HasPositions())
        {
            for (int v = 0; v != mesh->mNumVertices; v++)
            {
                norms = D3DXVECTOR3(0,0,0);
                if (mesh->HasNormals())
                    norms =  D3DXVECTOR3(mesh->mNormals[v].x,mesh->mNormals[v].y,mesh->mNormals[v].z);

                tanx = tany = tanz = 0;
                bitanx = bitany = bitanz = 0;

                if (mesh->HasTangentsAndBitangents())
                {
                    tanx = mesh->mTangents[v].x; tany = mesh->mTangents[v].y; tanz = mesh->mTangents[v].z;
                    bitanx = mesh->mBitangents[v].x; bitany = mesh->mBitangents[v].y; bitanz = mesh->mBitangents[v].z;
                }

                Vertices.push_back(MESH_STRUCT(
                    mesh->mVertices[v].x,
                    mesh->mVertices[v].y,
                    mesh->mVertices[v].z,
                    norms,
                    0,
                    0,
                    tanx, // TANGENTS
                    tany,
                    tanz
                ));

                for (int b = 0; b < mesh->mNumBones; b++)
                {
                    if (b > 4)
                        break;

                    float weight = 0.0f;

                    for ( int w = 0; w < mesh->mBones[b]->mNumWeights; w++)
                        if (mesh->mBones[b]->mWeights[w].mVertexId == v)
                            weight = mesh->mBones[b]->mWeights[w].mWeight;

                    Vertices.back().bWeight[b] = weight;
                }

                if (mesh->HasTextureCoords(0))
                {
                    Vertices.back().U = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][v].x;
                    Vertices.back().V = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][v].y;
                }
            }

            for (int f = 0; f != mesh->mNumFaces; f++)
            {
                for (int index = 0; index != mesh->mFaces[f].mNumIndices; index++)
                {
                    indices.push_back(mesh->mFaces[f].mIndices[index]);
                }
            }
        }

        data.meshData.push_back(Vertices);
        data.indices.push_back(indices);

        // Set the required textures
        const aiMaterial* pMaterial = scene->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex];

        if (pMaterial->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE) > 0) {
            aiString Path;

            if (pMaterial->GetTexture(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, 0, &Path, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == AI_SUCCESS) {
                std::string FullPath = Path.data;

                if (FullPath.find("\\") != string::npos)
                    FullPath = FullPath.substr(FullPath.find_last_of("\\")+1, FullPath.length() - (FullPath.length() - FullPath.find_last_of("\\")-1));
                else if (FullPath.find("/") != string::npos)
                    FullPath = FullPath.substr(FullPath.find_last_of("/")+1, FullPath.length() - FullPath.find_last_of("/")-1);

                string rFile = pFile;
                string spFile = std::string(pFile);

                if (spFile.find("\\") != string::npos)
                    rFile = spFile.substr(0, spFile.find_last_of("\\")+1);
                else
                    rFile = spFile.substr(0, spFile.find_last_of("/")+1);

                FullPath = rFile + FullPath;

                data.textures.push_back(FullPath);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            data.textures.push_back("");
        }
    }

    data.scene = scene;
    return data;
}
```

Comment: The error looks like memory corruption. Which functions are exported/imported from DLLs? How and when are they called?

Comment: That is one long function.  Can you boil it down to a smaller example which still reproduces the problem?

Comment: this function is defined in the graphics dll, and is called in the executable file, as well in the engine dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using STL objects as parameters and/or return types of the functions/methods you are exporting on your DLL.

Example: You return FMESH_DATA. This class/struct has STL objects inside, as we can see via line:

```
data.Keys.push_back(key);
```

The thing here is: It's not a good idea to have STL stuff being exported or imported via DLLs. It requires the caller of your DLL to use the same CRT of the objects that are created in the DLL.

But if you really wanna do that, you may change the Runtime Library of your projects (all of them) to multi-threaded (/MD). Then you will be able to use STL safely across the cliend and the DLL.

Comment: This might be the solution, just wait for me to test.